# How to set event listner on a QML object received say from QDeclarativeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

We had an object that we instatniated in our main programm and passed it into QML View. There were defined a `Q_PROPERTY`. I wonder how to set event listner on to `NOTIFY` signal?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Do you want a signal emitted from a property defined in C++ to be handled in your QML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, [this Qt DevNet forum post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9657) has a setup similar to yours. Only in that case they are defining the `READ` function which in turn emits the `somethingHappened` signal. Be sure to scroll all the way down to the last comments for the working example.

In summary, you have something like this defined in your C++ header file:

```
class SomeClass : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(sometype someProperty READ getSomeProperty NOTIFY somePropertyChanged)
signals:
  void somePropertyChanged();
 };
QML_DECLARE_TYPE(SomeClass)
```

Something like this in your C++ main method:

```
qmlRegisterType<SomeClass>("SomeModule", 1, 0, "SomeClass");
SomeClass myObj;
QDeclarativeView view;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rootItem", (SomeClass *)&myObj);
```

Then on the QML side you would handle it like this:

```
import SomeModule 1.0

SomeClass {
    onSomePropertyChanged: {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```